# Load fixed width file with backslash characters MYSQL

Tags: mysql, backslash

I am trying to load a data file into MySQL.
This file does not have delimiters so I have to go by positions.
but the problem is there are some backslashes in some column data.
So, these backslashes are omitted when loaded into MySQL.
I've tried to replace \ with \ in the file beforehand, but in that case,
the position of the data is compromised.

for example, my data file is like :

```
1  34  abc   de\f 583
```

so, if I replace \ with \\, the next data (583 in this case) will be read wrongly.

I've used `FIELDS ESCAPED by '\\'` already.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: replace \ with \\ and you should be through

Comment: I tried to replace \ with \\ but in that case, the data after that column is misaligned.